# VBScript nested class data structure

Tags: arrays, class, vbscript, nested-class

My problem can be illustrated in the following example code, which sets up a data array of friends, each of which can have several phone numbers:

```
Class clsPhoneNo
  Dim strType
  Dim strNumber
End Class

Class clsPerson
  Dim strName
  Dim aclsPhoneNo()
End Class

Dim clsFriends()
ReDim clsFriends(3)
Set clsFriend(0) = New Person
clsFriend(0).strName = "Fred"
Set clsFriends(0).aclsPhoneNo(0) = New clsPhoneNo
ReDim clsFriend(0).aclsPhoneNo(2)
Set clsFriend(0).aclsPhoneNo(0).strType = "Home"
Set clsFriend(0).aclsPhoneNo(0) = "01234567890"
Set clsFriend(0).aclsPhoneNo(1).strType = "Work"
Set clsFriend(0).aclsPhoneNo(1) = "09876543210"
```

However, VBScript says

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement
```

Before the . on the second ReDim statement

I need to have the aclsPhoneNo element variable length as my code isn't really an address book, but this is a simple example demonstrating the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `Dim clsFriends()` to `Dim clsFriends`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Arrays are the wrong data structure to solve this problem. They are the weapon of choice in other languages, they are not in VBScript, for they are notoriously inflexible.

Consider using [Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. And drop the Hungarian.

```vb
Dim phoneBook: Set phoneBook = New ObjectList

With phoneBook.Append(New Person)
  .Name = "fred"
  .AddPhoneNo "Home", "01234567890"
  .AddPhoneNo "Work", "09876543210"
End with

Dim pers: Set pers = phoneBook.Item(1)

For Each id In pers.PhoneNos.List
  Set num = pers.PhoneNos.List(id)
  WScript.Echo pers.Name & " #" & id & ": " & _
               num.Number & " (" & num.Label & ")"
Next

' ------------------------------------------------------
Class ObjectList
  Public List

  Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  End Sub

  Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set List = Nothing
  End Sub

  Function Append(Anything) 
    List.Add CStr(List.Count + 1), Anything 
    Set Append = Anything
  End Function

  Function Item(id) 
    If List.Exists(CStr(id)) Then
      Set Item = List(CStr(id))
    Else
      Set Item = Nothing
    End If
  End Function
End Class

' ------------------------------------------------------
Class PhoneNo
  Public Label
  Public Number
End Class

' ------------------------------------------------------
Class Person
  Public Name
  Public PhoneNos

  Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set PhoneNos = New ObjectList
  End Sub

  Function AddPhoneNo(Label, Number)
    Set AddPhoneNo = New PhoneNo
    With PhoneNos.Append(AddPhoneNo)
      .Label  = Label
      .Number = Number
    End With
  End Function
End Class
```

Note that I made use of a few VB features here

- You can use functions and classes before they are defined in the script, so put all your plumbing at the bottom.
- You can have `Public` and `Private` class variables
- Classes have an `Initiate` and a `Terminate` event that you can react to
- Function names are variable declarations. No need to declare a temporary return variable in a function, you can use the function name for that.
- The `With` block can save you a temporary variable as well.
- Even though the dictionary is comparatively convenient, it can still benefit from convenience wrapper, so I created one.

Comment: Cheers. I'll look at your answer in more detail later.
P.S. I like Hungarian. Makes it much easier to understand

Comment: @Frink: Well, keep it, if you must. ;) I find that Hungarian disturbs me more than it helps me. Proper variable naming has more benefit than a three-letter-prefix, IMHO.

Comment: the naming convention I use is based on a VBA one, where you can indicate array, constant and scope as well as type in the prefix. Works for me, although I'm not sure how it's supposed to work for classes, as you can see! Thanks, I'll give you the answer tick for the help

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have done, thanks to Tomalak for the help.

```
Class PhoneNo_Class
  Dim strType
  Dim strNumber
End Class

Class Person_Class
  Dim strName
  Dim aclsPhoneNo()

  Sub Class_Initialize()
    strName = ""
    ReDim aclsPhoneNo(0)                 'Set up entry 0 which is never used but prevents errors accessing UBound etc.
    Set aclsPhoneNo(0) = New PhoneNo_Class
  End Sub

  Sub AddPhoneNo(ByRef rstrType, ByRef rstrNumber)
    ReDim Preserve aclsPhoneNo(UBound(aclsPhoneNo) + 1)
    Set aclsPhoneNo(UBound(aclsPhoneNo)) = New PhoneNo_Class
    With aclsPhoneNo(UBound(aclsPhoneNo))
      .strType   = rstrType
      .strNumber = rstrNumber
    End With
End Sub

End Class

Dim clsFriends()
ReDim clsFriends(3)
Set clsFriends(1) = New Person_Class
With clsFriends(1)
  .strName = "Fred"
  .AddPhoneNo "Home", "01234567890"
  .AddPhoneNo "Work", "09876543210"
  WScript.Echo .strName & "'s " & .aclsPhoneNo(2).strType & " phone number is " & .aclsPhoneNo(2).strNumber
End With
```

This keeps my structure the same, and is a bit simpler (to my mind, anyway)

I suppose you could invent some sort of ReDim function in the Person_Class to perform a ReDim on its array members. That'd be nice...

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` is not very efficient, as it creates a copy of the array instead of appending to it. It's not very elegant, either. Just avoid arrays for this kind of work, or include a buffer instead of calling `ReDim` every turn. You could use steps of, say, 10 and include a counter in your class to remember how many slots are *actually* filled, for example. It's all not very nice with arrays, though.